# proftpd won't start

Tags: server, ftp

When trying to start proftpd server I get the following:

> /etc/init.d/proftpd start
>   ProFTPD warning: cannot start neither in standalone nor in inetd/xinetd mode. Check your configuration.

I don't know what to check for.
Help will be appreciated.